# How to set the current users email address in ASP.NET Membership?

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership

im trying to set the current users email from within asp.net

```
Membership.GetUser().Email = txtEmail.Text;
Membership.UpdateUser(Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name));
```

but the next time i read the current users Email it has not changed

i read it like this

```
Membership.GetUser().Email
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `Membership.GetUser()` returns a new user instance. Your first line is changing the Email property, and then proceeds by throwing away that change. Your second line will fetch the user again, with the old user, and update it.

The documentation for [Membership.UpdateUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.updateuser(v=vs.110).aspx) contains an example of updating the email property. It all boils down to passing the same User instance from `Membership.GetUser()` to `Membership.UpdateUser`.

```
// GetUser() without parameter returns the current logged in user.
MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser();       
u.Email = email;    
Membership.UpdateUser(u);
```

This will cause issues if you have a custom MembershipProvider that uses the email field for identification purposes (and you login with email+password), then the user would still have `User.Identity.Name` equal to the old email until next login (or they get a new Forms-cookie).

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);       
u.Email = email;    
System.Web.Security.Membership.UpdateUser(u);
```

Looks like you aren't feeding in the current user name to get user.